# How do you get a successful response from POST oauth/request_token in the Twitter API?

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

I'm having no luck trying to get a successful response from `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`, I've spent a long time reading the docs to try and build a header string that will give me an access token from the API. I've been following https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

and I've come up with this so far -

```
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const timestamp = new Date().getTime();

(async () => {
  const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64');
  const signature = getNewSignature();

  const params = {
    oauth_callback: 'http://localhost:3000',
    oauth_consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_nonce: nonce,
    oauth_signature: signature,
    oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
    oauth_token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  let headerString = 'OAuth ';
  const headerStringParams = Object.keys(params);
  for (let i = 0; i < headerStringParams.length; i++) {
    const param = headerStringParams[i];
    headerString += `${encodeURIComponent(param)}="${encodeURIComponent(params[param])}"`;

    if (i < headerStringParams.length - 1) {
      headerString += ', ';
    }
  }

  try {
    const result = await axios.post('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: headerString
      }
    });

    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.response);
  }
})();

function getNewSignature() {
  const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64');
  const params = {
    include_entities: true,
    oauth_consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_nonce: nonce,
    oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
    oauth_token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  let signatureString = '';
  const paramKeys = Object.keys(params);

  for (let i = 0; i < paramKeys.length; i++) {
    const param = paramKeys[i];
    signatureString += `${encodeURIComponent(param)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[param])}`;
    if (i < paramKeys.length - 1) {
      signatureString += '&';
    }
  }

  const signatureBaseString = `${encodeURIComponent('POST')}&${encodeURIComponent('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')}&${encodeURIComponent(signatureString)}`;
  const signingKey = `${encodeURIComponent(process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET)}&${encodeURIComponent(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)}`;
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', signingKey).update(signatureBaseString).digest('base64');

  return signature;
}
```

What this returns is `{ code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.' }`

I'm clearly doing something wrong and I just need someone to be a rubber duck and tell me where I've gone wrong! Thanks in advance

Comment: This error usually occurs when value of any required parameter is missing in the requested end point. Check and verify if all keys have proper values and not null or empty

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've been through this process multiple times, I'm hoping to get more than just "read the docs".

Comment: It looks like the code generates the `nonce` twice rather than passing it to the signature me